# Why do I only encounter CORS error when running GET request onChange?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, here-api

I am using a Create-React-App Client with a `proxy: "localhost:5000` set in the `package.json` to allow easy querying of the API on our Node.js server.

I am attempting to use HERE's autocomplete API using the following function.

**Auto Complete Function:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import hereKeys from '../config/hereConfig';

export const autoCompleteFullAddress = async query => {
  let address = null;
  try {
    await axios
      .get('https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json', {
        params: {
          app_id: hereKeys.appId,
          app_code: hereKeys.appCode,
          query: query,
          maxresults: 1,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        address = response.data.suggestions[0].address;
      });
  } finally {
    return address;
  }
};
```

I have a helper function in the component being rendered to execute this based off the user's input into an input field.

**Input Component:**

```
 const [puAddress, setPuAddress] = useState('');
 const [puQuery, setPuQuery] = useState('');

  const onAddressInput = e => {
    const query = e.target.value;

// This Fails
    autoCompleteFullAddress(query).then(suggestion => {
      setPuQuery(query);
      console.log(suggestion);
    });
  };

// This works
  autoCompleteFullAddress('37044 Even Lane').then(suggestion => {
    console.log(suggestion);
  });

return (
  <TextField
     value={puQuery}
     onChange={e => onAddressInput(e)}
  />
);
```

When `autoCompleteFullAddress` runs on its own it `console.log`'s the correct output. But once I try to execute this on the component's change it fails and throws an error.

**Error Thrown:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?
app_id=REDACTED&app_code=REDACTED&query=Elm+St&maxresults=1' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

**And:**

```
OPTIONS https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?
app_id=REDACTED&app_code=REDACTED&query=Elm+St&maxresults=1 405
```

**The Failed Request Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/pricing-tool
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

**Successful Request Headers:**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/pricing-tool
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Check the status code and possible response in the network tab of console.

Comment: 405 Error posted above.

Comment: I did before I posted. The comments don't offer any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people in the future who may be setting an access token like so in order to make requests to your API. The issue is it is trying to send the Auth header with the token on all Axios requests.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = token => {
  if (token) {
    const bearerToken = 'Bearer ' + token;
    // Apply to every request
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = bearerToken;
  } else {
    // Delete auth header
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
  }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

Can fix by changing the logic, or simply using fetch for external API's.

I fixed deleting the header on that specific request.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import hereKeys from '../config/hereConfig';

export const autoCompleteFullAddress = async query => {
  let address = null;
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
  try {
    await axios
      .get('https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json', {
        crossdomain: true,
        params: {
          app_id: hereKeys.appId,
          app_code: hereKeys.appCode,
          query: query,
          maxresults: 1,
          country: 'USA,MEX,CAN',
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        address = response.data.suggestions[0].address;
      });
  } finally {
    return address;
  }
};
```